# How to fix GoNative Android application not loading Laravel / Vue JS? Debug shows Syntax errors

Tags: android, vue.js, laravel-mix

I have a web app built in Laravel 5.5 and VueJS 2.7.12. We are using Laravel Mix to mix most of our assets, so we are using Webpack 3.12.0

We used GoNative to build the mobile native apps. Our IOS app is working but our android build is not loading. I am debugging the build and this is what I see:

Syntax error [ in app.js  Jquery , $ are undefined.

And a few other errors I'm assuming in my footer

[image]

I can't really see my sources in the console to see where the syntax error is, but I still want to ask if anyone has experienced incompatibility issues. Yesterday, I tried to upgrade my babel to latest, and installed babel-presets-vue but don't see much of an improvement.

I'm not using babel loader which I will try using now.

I'm using extracting jquery in my webpack.mix.js which looks like this

```
const { mix } = require('laravel-mix');

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------      ------
| Mix Asset Management */


if (mix.inProduction()) {
 mix.version();
}
mix.copyDirectory([

'resources/assets/vendor/ampleadmin/plugins/bower_components/ckeditor'],
'public/js/ckeditor'
);

mix.copy(['resources/assets/vendor/ampleadmin/plugins/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js','resources/assets/vendor/ampleadmin/js/custom.min.js,'resources/assets/vendor/ampleadmin/js/dashboard1.js','resources/assets/vendor/ampleadmin/plugins/bower_components/raphael/raphael-min.js',    'resources/assets/vendor/ampleadmin/plugins/bower_components/morrisjs/morris.min.js','resources/assets/vendor/ampleadmin/js/cbpFWTabs.js'], 'public/js');

mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
.extract(['vue', 'jquery', 'axios',  'moment', 'laravel-echo', 'pusher-js']).version();

mix.autoload({
jquery: ['$', 'window.jQuery', 'jQuery'],
moment: 'moment',
DataTable : 'datatables.net-bs'

});

mix.sourceMaps();

// mix.options();

mix.options({
// extractVueStyles: false,
processCssUrls: false
// postCss: [require('autoprefixer')],
 });
mix.webpackConfig({
resolve: {
    alias: {
        'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.min.js',
        'jquery-ui': 'jquery-ui-dist/jquery-ui.js',
    }
}
});
```

And this is my list of dependencies in package.json

```
 {
 "private": true,
 "scripts": {
 "dev": "npm run development",
"development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
"watch": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
"watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
"hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
"prod": "npm run production",
"production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
 },
 "babel": {
 "plugins": [
  "jsx-event-modifiers",
  "transform-vue-jsx"
],
"ignore": [],
"presets": [
  [
    "env",
    {
      "targets": {
        "node": "current"
      }
    }
  ],
  "vue"
 ]
 },
  "devDependencies": {
  "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic": "^10.1.0",
  "axios": "^0.17",
  "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
  "babel-preset-vue": "^2.0.2",
  "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
  "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.7",
  "chartist": "^0.9.7",
  "cross-env": "^5.2.0",
  "datatables.net": "^1.10.19",
  "datatables.net-bs": "^1.10.19",
  "file-loader": "^1.1.11",
  "imports-loader": "^0.8.0",
  "jquery": "^3.3.1",
  "jquery-migrate": "3.0.0",
  "jquery-noconflict": "^1.0.0",
  "jquery-ui": "^1.12.1",
  "jquery-ui-dist": "^1.12.1",
  "laravel-mix": "^1.7.2",
  "less": "^3.8.0",
  "less-loader": "^4.1.0",
  "lodash": "^4.17.10",
  "moment-timezone": "^0.5.21",
  "quill": "^1.3.6",
  "raphael": "^2.2.7",
  "sass-loader": "^5.0.1",
  "style-loader": "^0.17.0",
  "toastr": "^2.1.4",
  "vue": "^2.5.17",
  "vue-loader": "^12.2.2",
  "vue-resource": "^1.5.1",
  "vuex": "^3.0.1",
  "webpack-cli": "^2.1.5"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "api-ai-javascript": "^2.0.0-beta.14",
    "apiai": "^4.0.3",
    "babel": "^6.23.0",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "bootstrap-loader": "^2.2.0",
    "bootstrap-select": "^1.13.1",
    "browser-sync": "^2.24.6",
    "buble": "^0.15.2",
   "buble-loader": "^0.4.1",
   "daterangepicker": "^3.0.3",
   "express": "^4.15.3",
   "file-loader": "^1.1.11",
   "fs": "0.0.1-security",
   "fullcalendar": "^3.9.0",
  "fullcalendar-scheduler": "^1.9.4",
  "gulp-sass": "^3.1.0",
  "icheck": "^1.0.2",
  "image-picker": "^0.3.1",
  "install": "^0.10.4",
  "ioredis": "^2.5.0",
  "jquery-slimscroll": "^1.3.8",
  "jquery-ui-touch-punch": "^0.2.3",
  "laravel-echo": "^1.4.0",
  "moment": "^2.22.2",
  "morris.js": "^0.5.0",
  "node-sass": "^4.9.2",
  "npm": "^5.10.0",
  "pusher-js": "^4.2.1",
  "select2": "^4.0.6-rc.1",
  "socket.io": "^1.7.4",
  "timepicker": "^1.11.12",
  "vue-bootstrap-toggle": "^1.1.4",
  "vue-chat-scroll": "^1.3.3",
  "vue-js-modal": "^1.3.16",
  "vue-router": "^3.0.1",
  "vue-select": "^2.4.0",
  "vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.17",
  "webpack": "^3.12.0"
}
```

}

I can't see all my sources loaded in webview dev tools but not the source code.
[image]

[image]

Comment: I just found this and looking into it https://alligator.io/vuejs/demistifying-vue-webpack/. But really could use help from experienced developers here. I couldn't get any help from goNative support.

Comment: you should click on tab `Sources` ...

Comment: @MartinZeitler yes I tried looking at Sources. I can see that all files are loaded that is showing, but I can't see the actual code under sources, so I don't know where the syntax error is coming from or what line it is on. I think it has to do with dev tools in chrome.

Comment: of course one can see the sources there; how you think I debug my JS applications? the `$` is most likely jQuery not being loaded ...or loaded in the wrong order. with `chrome://inspect` you could even debug it on hardware.

Comment: I added screenshots of what I see in under sources tab. Like I said I can see that they are loaded and can't see the source code. Thanks any way I was asking if someone who experienced this problem like I am or knows of any known issues. @MartinZeitler

Comment: an empty response makes no sense, when it says `[ in app.js` ...it looks slightly different than what I have here (Chrome on Linux); nevertheless it should be possible to click just any script and then select `open in new tab`; if that file is indeed empty, the server (or build process) might not deliver it correctly.